# Does stringr replace base-R's string manipulation functions?

Tags: r, stringr

I am just about to embark on learning more about string manipulation in R. In general, I'm a great fan of Hadley Wickham's packages, as they tend to make programming in R much easier. Having said that, does `stringr` replace all Base-R's string manipulation functions? Meaning - is there things I can't do in `stringr` that I can do in Base-R? If so, what are these things?

Comment: This question is just too broad now. Zillions of things vaguely "string manipulation"-related aren't within stringr's purview.

Comment: I don't think you can be an `R` developer without knowing/using functions like `paste`, `as.character`, `nchar`, etc. Even though `stringr` is a great package and provides wrappers/alternatives for these 1) most people use the base R functions and 2) do you really want to have to import a package just to do something as simple as `paste`?

Comment: R can be inconsistent, so I believe the question is valid, even if not what StackOverflow wants. As a constructive variant of konvas's comment: 1) Learn `paste0`, with focus on what `collate` does. 2) Use the functions in `stringr` for everything else; they are consistent; 3) use `sprintf` for cases where R's habit of removing trailing zeroes gives trouble; 4) use the other functions for fringe cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `stringr` doesn't have a `sprintf` function or similar. How many examples do you want?

Comment: If there are general patterns/tasks where learning Base-R is useful vis-a-vis learning stringr, then that would be helpful.

Comment: Well I was answering the last of the stream of questions in the post. Yes, there are things you can't do in `stringr`.

Comment: Don't "learn stringr". Figure out what you need to do, then learn how to find out how to do that. Otherwise you'll be trying to hammer in nails with a screwdriver.